# How to implement a list of jobs which can be executed one after another or stopped at any time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing a Swing application which basically collects jobs (tasks) in a list and executes them one after another. I have 2 buttons: "Start" and "Stop". "Start" should start the execution and while the jobs are worked off it should be possible to click "Stop" to stop the execution.

I think I have to use multi-threading to be able to interrupt the execution at any time. But I am not really well versed with multi-threading and I think I am missing the correct approaches.

So far I have an interface for the jobs:

```
public interface Job {

    void start();

    void interrupt();

}
```

This way it's possible for implementing classes to extend `Thread`. But if I then start the execution of the list, start would immediately return and the next job would be started although the last job has not finished. If I would wait for the execution with `.join()` I would not be able to interrupt the job.

At the moment the jobs are worked off like this (`jobs` has the type `List<Job>`):

```
public void startWork() {
    while (!jobs.isEmpty()) {
        jobs.get(0).start();
        jobs.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea for my problem? I am really stuck.

**Update**

Thank you for your answers!

I am able to start the jobs now. My `JobManager` now looks like this:

```
public final class JobManager {

    /**
     * The list of jobs.
     */
    private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

    /**
     * The worker thread.
     */
    private ExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    /**
     * Works off the job list.
     */
    public void startWork() {
        worker.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!jobs.isEmpty()) {
                    jobs.get(0).start();
                    jobs.remove(0);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Stops the work off.
     */
    public void stopWork() {
        worker.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

But there is a problem with `shutdownNow()`. Inside a job I would have to check periodically if the Thread is interrupted. Is it possible to completely kill a thread?
I think those periodically checks would be a big overhead and I would always have to make sure that a job really checks for interrupts.

Comment: Can you use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)?

Comment: How many jobs do you have running at same time?

Comment: Only one. They should be executed in order and the next job should start after the preceding is done.

Comment: If I would use a `Future` I would have to do polling in my `startWork()` method if I'm correct. Wouldn't it be a waste of time or is there a possibility to abandon the CPU inside a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood correctly, you want run your Jobs one by one - in other words you dont need your Job to be an Thread/Runnable.

Rather , the process which executes the Jobs should be in Thread, So that your Swing Application can start / stop when it required.

if the above assumption is correct ..

Define Job as

```
interface Job{
    void start();
    boolean isCompleted();
}
```

And Actual Job as

```
class JobInstance implements Job {

String name;
boolean isCompleted;

public JobInstance(String name) {
    this.name  = name;
}


/**
 * @return the isCompleted
 */
public boolean isCompleted() {
    return isCompleted;
}


@Override
public void start() {

    System.out.println("Job "+this.name+" Started");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Job "+this.name+" Completed");
        isCompleted = true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Interuppted.. Mark me finish / dont remove from List");
    }


}
```

}

If no Interrup fired , this job will work in normal way and mark as completed.
Make the Class which is executing this job as runnable as

```
public class Process implements Runnable{

List<Job> jobLists;

public Process(List<Job> lists) {
    this.jobLists = lists;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    while(!jobLists.isEmpty()){
        Job job = jobLists.get(0);
        job.start();
        if (job.isCompleted()){
            jobLists.remove(0);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Interrup issuesed");
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

}

You can verify this using the following...

```
JobInstance job1 = new JobInstance("A");
    JobInstance job2 = new JobInstance("B");
    ArrayList<Job> jobLists = new ArrayList<>();
    jobLists.add(job1);
    jobLists.add(job2);
    Process process = new Process(jobLists);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread thread = new Thread(process);
    thread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    thread.interrupt();
```

Let me know if you need any info..

Note** , I thought demonstrate using basic thread , there are lot of ways to achive the same using Executors and so.

### **UPDATE**

if your Task/Process is not blocking , then issuing interrupt will not stop the thread. check Thread.interrupt doc/spec for more details.

if you planning to stop the non blocking task/ job then please find the follow sample using executorService

JOb Manager - as per your spec starts only one thread.

```
public final class JobManager {


public JobManager(List<Runnable> jobs){
    this.jobs = jobs;
}
/**
 * The list of jobs.
 */
private  List<Runnable> jobs = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

/**
 * The worker thread.
 */
private final ExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

/**
 * Works off the job list.
 */
public void startWork() {

    for (Iterator<Runnable> iterator = jobs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Runnable task =  iterator.next();
        worker.execute(task);
    }
}

/**
 * Stops the work off.
 */
public void stopWork() {
    worker.shutdownNow();
    jobs.clear();
}
}
```

Your task... Implement the process what ever in the run method.

```
class Task implements Runnable{
String name;


public Task(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Job "+this.name+" Started");
    long k=1;
    for(int i=0;i<=Integer.MAX_VALUE/1.5;i++){
        k = k +k;
    }

    System.out.println("Job  "+this.name+ "Completed");
}

 }
```

Test this with

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Task job1 = new Task("A");
Task job2 = new Task("B");
ArrayList<Runnable> jobLists = new ArrayList<>();
jobLists.add(job1);
jobLists.add(job2);
JobManager manager = new JobManager(jobLists);
manager.startWork();
try {
    Thread.sleep(150);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
manager.stopWork();
System.out.println("Issued Stop");
```

}

Comment: Inside a job would I have to check periodically if the thread was interrupted?

Comment: Not Required. if interrupt issued it would be automatically caught in InterruptedException block. Do what ever job you want to do instead of Thread.Sleep(10000). I used to sleep to demonstrate this example ( you dont required to keep any of the sleep)

Comment: if you want to do some action when the interrupt occurred, you can do that in  InterruptedException block.

Comment: Yes sure but if I remove `sleep()`, an `InterruptedException` would never be thrown and the JVM complains about the unreachable `catch` block. However, I had a talk with my boss and it is no problem if the currently running job finishes its work. So everything is fine now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Note** , if you are not blocking in your process then even issuing Interrupt will not work. Right of doing for just to stop the process ( please see the update)

Answer (score 2):

Don't subclass `Thread`! Especially if you want your jobs to run sequentially, this is not a good idea, as threads will run in parallel by definition.

Instead, use an `ExecutorService` with one single thread:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Then you can submit your jobs by wrapping them into a `Runnable`:

```
executor.execute(new JobTask(job));
```

Where `JobTask` is something like:

```
public class JobTask implements Runnable {
    private final Job job;

    public JobTask(Job job) { this.job = job; }

    public void run() {
        this.job.start();
    }
}
```

You will need some more code to implement the start/stop behaviour, as the executor immediately starts on its creation and throws away all pending tasks when it is stopped (See methods `shutdown`, `shutdownNow` and `awaitTermination`).

For more details, read [ExecutorService JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Java Concurrency Tutorial - Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Executors`, which is a factory for `ExecutorService`. With the method `shutdown()` you may stop the execution of tasks not yet started. With the method `shutdownNow()` you will interrupt already started tasks as well. Perhaps the method `awaitTermination()` is of interest as well to you. Just read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: [`ExecutorService#awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) should be called after `shutdown`. When you call `shutdown`, the `ExecutorService` doesn't allow to accept more jobs...

Comment: `Executors` sound promisingbut is there a way to keep my list (which is needed for the gui) in sync?

Comment: I don|t know what zou mean with in sync, but the `ExecutorService` has a method `submit()` which takes either a `Runnable` or a `Callable`. If you remove the task from your list and submit it to the `ExecutorService` you should be fine. Do you like to achieve anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop a thread once it's fired off and is executing the run() method, until the run method returns to completion.

.... Unless your thread does something cyclic. Like doing something within a while loop.

Threads are not meant to do heavy stuff anyways. If you want have a interrupt mechanism for your jobs consider spawning a process instead.

However, In case your thread does cyclic you can have a boolean class variable that you check against every time before you start the next iteration.

And you could change the state of the boolean variable if the "stop" button is pressed in your swing application. In doing so, the check would fail for the next iteration and your job thread's run method would return and join the main tread.

The ideal way to communicate between the main tread and job thread would be to implement a listener in the Job Thread and implement register the listener to your view. Or do it quick and dirty without following the observer pattern strictly.

```
 Class Job implements Runnable
 {
     private volatile boolean shouldRun=true;
     public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
              if(!shouldRun)
              {
                   //do clean up before exiting
                   break;
              }
              //do processing 
          }
      }

      public void stopEventAction()
      {
          shouldRun = false;
      }
   }
```

And just call the stopEventAction() on all your threads when you click stop.

Comment: `shouldRun` should be `volatile`.

Comment: "There is no way to stop a thread once it's fired off and is executing the run() method, until the run method returns to completion."  Not technically true. There may not be a good way to stop a thread, but there are bad ways (Thread#stop for example).

Comment: @Aurand True. But stop is deprecated http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html